# How to retrieve the data(String) from text file and send into particular field in application using java (selenium webdriver.)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to get the data from text file it worked , but unable to send the same data to particular field in application.

Comment: Please post the code you're using. Also add a tag to the post to indicate the language you're using (there are lots of languages with Selenium bindings). Lastly, add the version of Selenium you're using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Store that text in string variable and send it using sendKeys(your_string) method.